# How to get information of field on click

Tags: php, jquery

i am creating loop for text box and dropdown box...

```
foreach ($users as $user)
{
 echo '<div class="row">';
 echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$user['uid'].'" id="userid"/>';
 echo '<input type="text" value="'.$user['username'].'" disabled id="username"/>';
 echo '<select name="site" id="site"> <option>Site A</option><option>Site B</option></select>';
 echo '<select name="role" id="role">';
foreach ($roles as $role)
    echo '<option>'.$role.'</option>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<input type="button" name="Change" id="Change" value="Change" onclick="getClick()">';
}
```

my jquery is

```
function getClick()
{
     var a=$("#username").val();
     alert(a);
}
```

now problem is when i click on any **change** button i am getting username of **first row** only... how can i get username for each row...

Comment: for that you have to give seperate id for each fields

Comment: can you share the rendered html structure.?

Comment: here you are creating multiple elements with the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a class value instead of `id` because the elements are created within a loop - id of an element must be unique in a document.

So change all `id`s to `class`

```
'<input type="hidden" value="'.$user['uid'].'" class="userid"/>'
```

Also use jQuery event handlers instead of inlined one

```
'<input type="button" name="Change" value="Change" class="change">'

jQuery(function(){
    $('.change').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this), $row = $this.closest('.row');
        var a=$row.find(".username").val();
        alert(a);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify the code as given below:

```
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$user['username'].'" disabled 
     id="username"'.$user['uid'].'"/>';

echo '<input type="button" name="Change" id="Change" value="Change"
      onclick="getClick("'.$user['uid'].'")">';
```

**Javascript:**

```
function getClick(userid)
{
    var a=$("#username"+userid).val();
    alert(a);
}
```